# FluentUI dropdown not working in create-react-app

Tags: dropdown, create-react-app, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I created a create-react-app project on my machine.

I ran `npm i @fluentui/react` in my project directory terminal to install the fluent ui package.

I have simple code to display a dropdown, with all the correct imports

```
import { Dropdown, DropdownMenuItemType, IDropdownStyles, IDropdownOption } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Dropdown';

const dropdownStyles: Partial<IDropdownStyles> = {
  dropdown: { width: 300 },
};

const options: IDropdownOption[] = [
  { key: 'fruitsHeader', text: 'Fruits', itemType: DropdownMenuItemType.Header },
  { key: 'apple', text: 'Apple' },
  { key: 'banana', text: 'Banana' },
  { key: 'orange', text: 'Orange', disabled: true },
  { key: 'grape', text: 'Grape' },
  { key: 'divider_1', text: '-', itemType: DropdownMenuItemType.Divider },
  { key: 'vegetablesHeader', text: 'Vegetables', itemType: DropdownMenuItemType.Header },
  { key: 'broccoli', text: 'Broccoli' },
  { key: 'carrot', text: 'Carrot' },
  { key: 'lettuce', text: 'Lettuce' },
];

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <Dropdown
        placeholder="Select an option"
        options={options}
        styles={dropdownStyles}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

What is getting displayed is a weird box with no clickable dropdown.
[image]

I did some research and I needed to import the icons so I added such code to my project.

```
import { initializeIcons } from "@fluentui/react/lib/Icons";

initializeIcons();
```

Now the dropdown displays the correct icon however nothing happens onclick of the icon.
[image]

Weirdly enough, when the screen size is tablet sized the dropdown will show up as context pane but will not appear in full screen mode
[image]

Ive searched SO and haven't found any answers to this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you want to disable responsive mode:

```
import { ResponsiveMode } from '@fluentui/react'

<Dropdown
  ...
  responsiveMode={ResponsiveMode.unknown}
/>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/XWEmBNN?editors=0010) working example.

Comment: no, the dropdown still isn't working onclick

Comment: @cameron did you check console? Please provide codepen example

Answer (score 0):

If you have <React.StrictMode>  in your index.tsx, you can remove this and then it works (at least for me when I was having the same issue).